# PHP Form Submitting

Tags: error-handling, php

I'm having a problem with my form,I'm displaying two rows from my DB which use the same form (using while loop) to put values back to the DB.The problem stands that the second or the bottom row that displays works fine,but the top one work for example if I click on the bottom one value 1 the top one works only if I click value 1 and after that stops working.

My website is **www.albsocial.us/test/seria.php** to check it out yourself,I included a video just in this case **http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGwPd_P65oM**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connect.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 2";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<h2>Seria A</h2><hr/>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $id = $row['id'];
    $home = $row['home'];
    $away = $row['away'];
    $win = $row['win'];
    $draw = $row['draw'];
    $lose = $row['lose'];


    echo "<br/>",$id,") " ,$home, " - ", $away;

    echo "

    <form action='seria.php' method='post' id='$id'>
    <select name='test'>        
        <option value=\"\">Parashiko</option>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='X'>X</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>            
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='id' readonly value='".$row['id']."'/>

   </select>        

    <br/>

    </form>";        

    echo "Totali ", $sum = $win+$lose+$draw, "<br/><hr/>"; 

} 

if (!empty($_POST)) {

  $id=isset($_POST['id'])&&is_numeric($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id']:false;

  $select = isset($_POST['test']) ? $_POST['test']:false;

  switch ($select) {
    case 1:
    $select = $win + $select;
    mysql_query("UPDATE test SET win='$select' WHERE id='$id'");
    break;

    case 'X':
    $select = '1';
    $select = $draw + $select;
    mysql_query("UPDATE test SET draw='$select' WHERE id='$id'");
    break;

    case 2:
    $select = '1';
    $select = $lose + $select;
    mysql_query("UPDATE test SET lose='$select' WHERE id='$id'");
    break;
    default:
  }
  header('Location: ../test/seria.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: no it will work for the whichever row id is on the bottom .. then if i click value=1 in the bottom the top will only work if i click the same value,button

Comment: no for example if i click the bottom row value i jusst want to submit that value .. then if i decide to click top one i should submit that value one @Prix

Comment: Check the video please. ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to update the values of wins, loses, an draws, by adding 1 to the selected choise, I have changed the code a bit as a suggestion, hope it wokrs.

```
<?php

session_start();

include("connect.php");

$submit = @$_POST["submit"];
$tests = @$_POST["test"];

// If the user submitted the form.
// Do the updating on the database.
if (!empty($submit))
{
    if (count($tests) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($tests as $test_id => $test_value)
        {
            switch ($test_value)
            {
                case 1:
                    mysql_query("UPDATE test SET win = win + 1 WHERE id = '$test_id'");
                break;

                case 'X':
                    mysql_query("UPDATE test SET draw = draw + 1 WHERE id = '$test_id'");
                break;

                case 2:
                    mysql_query("UPDATE test SET lose = lose + 1 WHERE id = '$test_id'");
                break;

                default:
                    // DO NO THING.
            }
        }
    }

    // Redirect to seria page.
    header('Location: ../test/seria.php');
}

// Whenever this wiil be fetched it will be updated.
$query = "SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 2";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<h2>Seria A</h2><hr/>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $id = $row['id'];
    $home = $row['home'];
    $away = $row['away'];
    $win = $row['win'];
    $draw = $row['draw'];
    $lose = $row['lose'];


    echo "<br/>",$id,") " ,$home, " - ", $away;

    echo "

    <form action='seria.php' method='post'>

    <select name='test[$id]'>        
        <option value=\"\">Parashiko</option>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='X'>X</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
   </select>

   <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>

    <br/>

    </form>";        

    echo "Totali ", $sum = $win+$lose+$draw, "<br/><hr/>"; 

} 

?>
```

Best regards,
Hussam.

Comment: Life saver my friend ... thanks a lot brother .. Great solution its working .. could you explain to me what did i do wrong .. i had to inlcude these ---> $submit = @$_POST["submit"];
$tests = @$_POST["test"]; and the foreach

Comment: I think you have divided your code into two parts, one is retrieving data from database and displaying it, and the other is saving (updating) data into database.

It would be much better, if the updating was first, because when you decide to query the database later, the data will be up-to-date.

Another thing is that you used many forms in the page, while you could use one form and use inputs as an array.

Comment: Thanks My friend .. Really helpful . Now i get it thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a while loop to show the HTML form, so when the form is submitted and you try to access `$_POST['test']` it receives only the last value, as HTML will override the values.

So what you have to do is just change the name of fields from `test` to `test[]`, now what happens is when you submit the form it will get error as `$_POST['test][0]`, `$_POST['test'][1]`, etc. and all values with index 0 will have the value of first field and all 1 have value of second form and so on.

Hope I make sense :).

Comment: Doesnt seem to work brother .. this is the line i need to change -->       $select = isset($_POST['test'][0]) ? $_POST['test'][0]:false;

Comment: did you change name attribute in HTML to "test[]" ?

Comment: <select name='test[]'>        
          <option value=\"\">Parashiko</option>
          <option value='1'>1</option>
          <option value='X'>X</option>
          <option value='2'>2</option>            
      </select>
 still not workking brother

Comment: try to print $_POST and change your logic according to theory I provided.